# How call and repeat a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, math, matrix

Basically my HW says to ask user for matrix of A. Then ask user by how much he would like to power Matrix A.

So basically,

I need to find a way to raise a matrix to the power. I can multiply them, but it's harder to raise them to the power because I must multiply it by itself. So What I do is create a variable to hold the matrix like so

```
for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
    {
        for (k = 0; k < matrixARowSize; k++)
        {
            sum += matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j];
        }
        matrixC[i][j] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Then I would have to multiply to itself as much as the user wants to.
Eg:

```
matrixC[i][j] * matrixC[i][j]*matrixC[i][j] ...// etc
```

up to whatever power the user wants. I can do that with many If statements yes, but I also need to be able to add them together like so:

```
matrixC^6 + matrixC^5 + matrixC^4 ...
```

etc from whatever power the user wants. (Highest is 6).

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: That's a 3d array, you're also trying to take a sum of arrays instead of elements for matrixA because of it.

Comment: thats just my partial code. I want to know how I can add its powers...

Comment: If you [Diagonalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) the matrix first powers become much easier, but requires [eigenvalue decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int raiseMethod(int val, int pow) {

    int temp = val;
    for (int i = 1; i < pow; i++) {

        temp *= val;
    }
    return temp;
}

for (int i = 0; i < arrayColummns; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < arrayRows; j++) {

        array[i][j] = raiseMethod(array[i][j], powerToRaise);
    }
}
```

This way, the array will be auto-updated with it's raised value on each position.

Comment: What it's your array Type?, i assumed you're using an int array

Comment: I''''''''''''''''''''''''']

Comment: Sorry about that ^^ lol . I meant the math not the arguements

Comment: I had a little issue on the raiseMethod, i was powering the number to powerToRaise + 1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `Math.pow()` method, which raises one number to the power of another, e.g.

```
    sum += (int) Math.power(matrixA[i][j], raiseByPower);
```

Comment: that wouldn't work. It would only raise each individual element to the power of whatever.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question so it can sound better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the binary multiplication of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This Matrix structure contains everything you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int SIZE = 6;

struct Matrix
{
    int m[SIZE][SIZE];

    Matrix()
    {
        memset(m,0,sizeof(m));
    }

    Matrix( int a[SIZE][SIZE] )
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<SIZE;++i)for(int j = 0;j<SIZE;++j)
        {
            m[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }

    Matrix operator * ( const Matrix &a )
    {
        Matrix ret;

        for(int k = 0;k<SIZE;++k) for(int i = 0;i<SIZE;++i) for(int j = 0;j<SIZE;++j)
        {
            ret.m[i][j] += m[i][k] * a.m[k][j];
        }
        return ret;
    }

    Matrix operator ^ ( int P )
    {
        Matrix ret , a(this->m);

        for(int i = 0;i<SIZE;++i)
            ret.m[i][i] = 1;

        while(P)
        {
            if( P&1 )
                ret = ret * a;

            a = a * a;
            P >>= 1;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    Matrix operator + (const Matrix &a)
    {
        Matrix ret;
        for(int i = 0;i<SIZE;++i) for(int j = 0;j<SIZE;++j)
        {
            ret.m[i][j] = m[i][j] + a.m[i][j];
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

You can use this structure like the following:

```
Matrix A, B;
Matrix res = (A^6) + (B^5);
```

This Power function does **log(n)** multiplications of matrix.

Comment: Wow, lol I can't even read this... It looks good, but I'm a noob at this. Is this even java though?... lol